# What objects can be classified as anonymous?

Tags: adjectives

While answering and commenting on [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17433/is-bestowing-anonymity-the-right-term-or-expression) I discovered that I am apparently thinking about anonymity differently than everyone else who responded. There are two questions stemming from that discussion, this is the first:

What words can fill the gap in this sentence?

> [Word] is anonymous.

The examples I seem to find acceptable:

> The writer is anonymous.
>
> The paper was anonymous.
>
> The call was anonymous.

Should I be saying:

> The paper was written anonymously.
>
> The call was made anonymously.

Comment: The only one that sounds odd is paper.  I don't know what sense of paper you mean, but it doesn't seem logical that a paper would be anonymous.  If you search BNC it comes up with nothing.  But uses like *anonymous letter*, for example, are quite common.

Comment: Yes, "letter" would a better word choice for what I was trying to ask. I meant "paper" as in a published paper which isn't likely to be published anonymously since recognition is half the reason it was published.

Comment: I agree with all of yur example sentences, though I would say that 'anonymous call' is also acceptable. Were you to say 'an anonymous paper' it might also be acceptable but would have a different meaning, i.e. that the paper had no name/title or that the paper you are referencing is being kept confidential.

Comment: I think *anonymous call* and *anonymous letter* are really common. So much so that I'd actually rather say *This is an anonymous letter* than *This letter is anonymous*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of your example sentences sound fine for me. In general, it's acceptable to refer to a piece of communication as being *anonymous* if what you mean is that it was *created anonymously*. This is a common idiom.

However, this doesn't necessarily apply to all words derived from the same stem. Saying *the writer's anonymity* sounds fine; saying *the paper's anonymity* strikes me as questionable. Others may find it to be unobjectionable, but I am among those speakers who would balk at the construction. Thus, for maximum clarity and fluency, you may find it useful to reword things like *the paper's anonymity* to *the anonymity of the paper's author*.

Comment: Right. "The paper was anonymous" sounds non-idiomatic. But: "We received an anonymous letter" would fly.

Comment: How about "The paper is anonymous"? Does that strike the same nerve as "The paper's anonymity"?

Comment: *A paper/poem/song by an anonimous* would be more appropriate I guess.

Comment: @nico: No. "an anonymous" without a noun is not possible in English.

Comment: When I was a kid I used to think that Anon was an ancient poet/philosopher. :D

Comment: @Colin Fine: the NOED says otherwise... in particular it says it is possible to use it as "nameless" (e.g. an anonymous book) and also as in "A person whose name is not given, or is unknown."

Comment: @nico: Isn't it usually capitalized, though? "Written by Anonymous"?

Comment: @MrHen: I'm not sure about that. My guess would be that either you say "Written by Anonymous" or "Written by an anonymous" (implying *an anonymous person*)